# Templated stream operators, unresolved externals

Tags: c++, templates

In a previous project I encountered similar errors, so I decided to start fresh from a new approach and am still getting the same issues. I have a key-value pair template class, and everything is working except for the stream operators. I have templates for `<<` accepting either a `kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp` or `kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp`. I am able to create `kvp_node` objects and use their member functions with no issues. But if I try to do something like:

```
kvp_node<char, int> test('A', 10);
std::cout << test;
```

It gives me the unresolved external operator error.
I feel as if I have defined my stream operators correctly. If I try to just do:

```
kvp_node<char, int> name('J', 12);
std::cout << name.elm_();
```

it works without error, and that is why this is confusing since all the ostream operator does is

`os << (kvp_node<key, elem> test(key, elem)).elm_()`

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef DICT_H_
#define DICT_H_
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>


//Stores Key Value pairs in a linked node can be used 
//to implement various KV based ADTs
//kvp_nodes can be compared using normal comparator
//operations. These operations will use the comparators
//for the key class type, so if the key class is a user
//defined type, they must define the comparators for the
//class
template<typename key, typename elem>
class kvp_node {
    bool setinel;
    key k_val;
    elem e_val;
    kvp_node<key, elem> *next;
    kvp_node<key, elem> *prev;
public:
    //default constructor
    kvp_node();
    //use this constructor
    kvp_node(key k, elem e, bool set = false);
    //destructor
    ~kvp_node();
    //copy constructor
    kvp_node(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    //assignment constructor
    void operator=(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp_);

    //returns keyvalue
    key key_();
    //returns element
    elem elm_();

    //sets key value
    void set_key(key k);
    //sets element value
    void set_elm(elem e);

    //comparators, all will use the default comparators for the key type
    bool operator==(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    bool operator>=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    bool operator<=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    bool operator>(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    bool operator<(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);

    //returns next node
    kvp_node<key, elem> *gnext();
    //returns previous node
    kvp_node<key, elem> *gprev();

    //node linking functions
    //sets the next node
    void set_next(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //sets the previous node
    void set_prev(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //links node a forward to b and b backward to a
    void link_nodes(kvp_node<key, elem> *A, kvp_node<key, elem> *B);

    //setinel functions
    //makes setinel
    void set_set();
    //returns setinel value
    bool set();

    //standard io stream operators
    //ostream <<
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //istream
    //add later

    //standard file stream operators
    //ofstream <<
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &fo, kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &fo, kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //ifstream
    //add later
};


//constructors, destructors, assignment
template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node() {
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node(key k, elem e, bool set) {
    k_val = k;
    e_val = e;
    setinel = set;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::~kvp_node(){

}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    k_val = kvp.key_();
    e_val = kvp.elm_();
    setinel = kvp.set();
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::operator=(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    k_val = kvp.key_();
    e_val = kvp.elm_();
    setinel = kvp.set();
}
// ==================================
//get object values
template<typename key, typename elem>
key kvp_node<key, elem>::key_() {
    return k_val;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
elem kvp_node<key, elem>::elm_() {
    return e_val;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::set() {
    return setinel;
}
// ==================================
//set object values
template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_key(key k) {
    k_val = k;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_elm(elem e) {
    e_val = e;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_set() {
    setinel = true;
}
// =================================
//get neighbor kv pair nodes
template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp_node<key, elem>::gnext() {
    return next;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp_node<key, elem>::gprev() {
    return prev;
}
// =================================
//set neighbor kv pair nodes
template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_next(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
    next = kvp;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_prev(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
    prev = kvp;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::link_nodes(kvp_node<key, elem> *A, kvp_node<key, elem> *B) {
    A->set_next(B);
    B->set_prev(A);
}
// ==================================
//comparison operators
template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator<(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    return (k_val < kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator>(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    return (k_val > kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator<=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    return (k_val <= kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator>=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    return (k_val >= kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator==(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    return (k_val == kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}
// ==================================
//stream operators

template<typename key, typename elem>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    os << kvp.elm_();
    return os;
}

template<typename key,typename elem>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
    os << kvp->elm_();
    return os;
}

#endif
```

How is it that I can use all other class members but the stream operators don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.  Here are my changes. (I shotgunned the submission, so forgive me while I fix the formatting).

- Removed the friend functions for the different operators.  Since you have getters, then those will suffice.
- Make all getters const.  If you try to use this inside an STL container, you will get errors for discarding qualifiers.
- Make all stream operators take a const instance of your class.

Code

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<fstream>


//Stores Key Value pairs in a linked node can be used 
//to implement various KV based ADTs
//kvp_nodes can be compared using normal comparator
//operations. These operations will use the comparators
//for the key class type, so if the key class is a user
//defined type, they must define the comparators for the
//class
template<typename key, typename elem>
class kvp_node {
    bool setinel;
    key k_val;
    elem e_val;
    kvp_node<key, elem> *next;
    kvp_node<key, elem> *prev;
public:
    //default constructor
    kvp_node();
    //use this constructor
    kvp_node(key k, elem e, bool set = false);
    //destructor
    ~kvp_node();
    //copy constructor
    kvp_node(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp);
    //assignment constructor
    void operator=(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp_);

    //returns keyvalue
    key key_()const;
    //returns element
    elem elm_()const;

    //sets key value
    void set_key(key k);
    //sets element value
    void set_elm(elem e);

    //comparators, all will use the default comparators for the key type
    bool operator==(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const;
    bool operator>=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const;
    bool operator<=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const;
    bool operator>(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const;
    bool operator<(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const;

    //returns next node
    kvp_node<key, elem> *gnext();
    //returns previous node
    kvp_node<key, elem> *gprev();

    //node linking functions
    //sets the next node
    void set_next(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //sets the previous node
    void set_prev(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp);
    //links node a forward to b and b backward to a
    void link_nodes(kvp_node<key, elem> *A, kvp_node<key, elem> *B);

    //setinel functions
    //makes setinel
    void set_set();
    //returns setinel value
    bool set()const;

};


//constructors, destructors, assignment
template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node() {
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node(key k, elem e, bool set) {
    k_val = k;
    e_val = e;
    setinel = set;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::~kvp_node(){

}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem>::kvp_node(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    k_val = kvp.key_();
    e_val = kvp.elm_();
    setinel = kvp.set();
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::operator=(const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
    k_val = kvp.key_();
    e_val = kvp.elm_();
    setinel = kvp.set();
}
// ==================================
//get object values
template<typename key, typename elem>
key kvp_node<key, elem>::key_()const{
    return k_val;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
elem kvp_node<key, elem>::elm_()const{
    return e_val;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::set()const{
    return setinel;
}
// ==================================
//set object values
template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_key(key k) {
    k_val = k;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_elm(elem e) {
    e_val = e;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_set() {
    setinel = true;
}
// =================================
//get neighbor kv pair nodes
template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp_node<key, elem>::gnext() {
    return next;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp_node<key, elem>::gprev() {
    return prev;
}
// =================================
//set neighbor kv pair nodes
template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_next(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
    next = kvp;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::set_prev(kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
    prev = kvp;
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void kvp_node<key, elem>::link_nodes(kvp_node<key, elem> *A, kvp_node<key, elem> *B) {
    A->set_next(B);
    B->set_prev(A);
}
// ==================================
//comparison operators
template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator<(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const{
    return (k_val < kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator>(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const{
    return (k_val > kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator<=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const{
    return (k_val <= kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator>=(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const{
    return (k_val >= kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
bool kvp_node<key, elem>::operator==(kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp)const{
    return (k_val == kvp.key_()) ? (true) : (false);
}
// ==================================
//stream operators

template<typename key, typename elem>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem>const& kvp) {
    os << kvp.key_() << ", " << kvp.elm_();
    return os;
}

template<typename key,typename elem>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem>const* kvp) {
    os << kvp->elm_();
    return os;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    kvp_node<int,double> foo01( 1, 2 );

    std::cout << foo01 << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, why does removing the stream operator declarations from the class fix the issue? Also what is the difference between `const kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp` and ` kvp_node<key, elem>const& kvp`

Comment: Removing the friend functions from the class does not fix the issue.  I just remove them because they are not necessary since you have getters for all of your private members.  The thing that fixed it was using const kvp_node instances inside the `operator <<` definition.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I can continue my project thanks to you :)

Comment: @Jordan: removing friend did fix the issue. Friend in templates are hard to correctly use because by default the compiler expects a non template version for the friend function. It is normally possible to force the compiler to use a template version by using forward declarations, by here it does not work because you have an indirect dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Friend templates are generally hard to implement correctly. In general, the best way is to declare them inline. That way, you could access private members:

```
template<typename key, typename elem>
class kvp_node {
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> &kvp) {
        os << kvp.e_val;
        return os;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, kvp_node<key, elem> *kvp) {
        os << kvp->e_val;
        return os;
    }

    ...
}
```

But I would never declare the operators for `std::ofstream` in addition to those ones, since a `std::ofstream` **is** a `std::ostream`, so the second definition is useless.

And I would not have `operator <<` take a pointer as if it was a reference. `cout` already knows how to display a pointer to any, and it does not display the pointed value. Displaying the pointed value in an API would confuse future users.